# when we are using swiper slider in angular 16 we are facing some issues

Tags: angular, slider, swiper.js

I am getting the following error when trying to compile my Angular application and do not know what is wrong.

What is this error message telling me and how do I fix it?

[image: VS Code with an Angular project open. A terminal window shows an Angular compiler error.]

Comment: Are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-useful-swiper?activeTab=readme ?

Comment: did you tried to install the dependeny that is saying there:    npm i swiper/bundle

Comment: I saw an integration with Angular 16 here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-keaszp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html